# setSeparator doesnt work for the QAction in qtitanribbon

Tags: qt, ribbon

I hit an issue in case of adding separators in the RibbonGroup in case of the following scenario:

- Create an action,
- Add to the RibbonGroup,
- Set action as a separator (QAction::setSeparator(true))

Actually, the separator appears as dummy text.

Are there any way to solve this problem ?

Thanks,